# Typescript convert an image url to base64 encoded string fails

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to convert an image to base 64 format, given its URL.

Below is my approach in order to achieve that:

```
getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

// Using the function above to do the conversion (an image to base 64 format from its URL);
this.getBase64Image('https://live.mystocks.co.ke/research/images/bamburi.jpg');
```

It fails.

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve it?

Comment: a string is not an image.

Comment: how then do i go about it?

Comment: What error do you get? Consider updating your post with that so as to make your question complete.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot get image information from a string, you need to load that image first so you'll need to return an `Observable` or a `Promise`:

```js
getBase64Image(img:HTMLImageElement) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}



getBase64ImageFromURL(url:string) {
  return Observable.create((observer:Observer<string>) => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    if (!img.complete) {
      img.onload = () => {
        observer.next(getBase64Image(img));
        observer.complete();
      };
      img.onerror = (err) => {
        observer.error(err);
      };
    } else {
      observer.next(getBase64Image(img));
      observer.complete();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported. (something has to do with Access Origin when pulling image from Amazon S3 or any other remote url).

Comment: "cors images" in google : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: but my code is not going in img.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
    localStorage.setItem( "savedImageData", canvas.toDataURL("image/png") );
}