# Ionic 2: Convert URL to base 64 image

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have image url, example: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lLC-FsscD40/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMp5VUoSrLythVKtt5Skm9zIUg4uyxnNCw/s48-c-mo/photo.jpg

Need to convert url to base 64 image, my code not working, help please:

```
convertToDataURLviaCanvas(url){
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

        let img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
        img.src = url;

        var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.createElement("canvas");

        canvas.width =img.width;
        canvas.height =img.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        resolve(dataURL);

    });
}
```

Comment: No late that this morning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792094/typescript-convert-an-image-url-to-base64-encoded-string-fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this work for me

```
   convertToDataURLviaCanvas(url, outputFormat){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = () => {
      let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        dataURL;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      canvas.width = img.width;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
      resolve(dataURL);
      canvas = null;
    };
    img.src = url;
  });
}
```

simple call

```
convertToDataURLviaCanvas(base64, "image/jpeg").then(base64 => console.log(base64))
```

Comment: I try this, but `img.onload = () => { ... }` not working.

Comment: No errors, image not loaded. I add code `img.onerror = (err) => { console.log(err) };` and get *"isTrusted":true*

Comment: After i update code, my errors: `Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`, `Property 'height' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`, `Property 'width' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

Comment: Code in block `img.onload = () => { ... }` not performed

Comment: try to replace  `img.height` and `img.width` with numbers for example 300 for both

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you can get the base64 data of the image:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let imageUrl = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lLC-FsscD40/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMp5VUoSrLythVKtt5Skm9zIUg4uyxnNCw/s48-c-mo/photo.jpg';

    this.getBase64ImageFromURL(imageUrl).subscribe(base64data => {
      console.log(base64data);
      this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'+base64data;
    });
  }

  getBase64ImageFromURL(url: string) {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<string>) => {
      let img = new Image();
      img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
      img.src = url;
      if (!img.complete) {
        img.onload = () => {
          observer.next(this.getBase64Image(img));
          observer.complete();
        };
        img.onerror = (err) => {
          observer.error(err);
        };
      } else {
        observer.next(this.getBase64Image(img));
        observer.complete();
      }
    });
  }

  getBase64Image(img: HTMLImageElement) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
  }
```

Working link to stackblitz: [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-imu9kj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I have tried this solution, and sometimes it works and at other times it shows me CORS error: No acces-control-allow-origin, I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in Headers, I add in htaccess:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
```